# Core Data and NSEntityDescription

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, core-data

I'm having a problem with Core Data on my iPhone app. Every time I try to call methods with `NSEntityDescription` I get an objc_exception_throw() (which I set in my symbolic breakpoints).

An example of a section in which I get an exception is:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
managedObjectContext = [favoritesFetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteAddress" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
favorites = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

managedObjectContext = [recentsFetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecentAddress"
                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
recents = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

[request release];
```

"FavoriteAddress" and "RecentAddress" are the names of my objects in my core data model. `favoritesFetchedResultsController` and `recentsFetchedResultsController` are both defined in the following methods:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)favoritesFetchedResultsController
{
NSLog(@"Favorites Fetched Results Controller called");
if(favoritesFetchedResultsController == nil)
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteAddress" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"FavoritesCache"];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.favoritesFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [request release];

}

return favoritesFetchedResultsController;
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)recentsFetchedResultsController
{
NSLog(@"Recent Fetched Results Controller called");

if(recentsFetchedResultsController == nil)
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecentAddress" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"RecentsCache"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.recentsFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [request release];
}

return recentsFetchedResultsController;
}
```

The backtrace I get when the exception is thrown is:

```
0  0x01703cb4 in objc_exception_throw ()
1  0x00fe6a87 in +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] ()
2  0x0001ca7f in -[SavedAddressesViewController getData] (self=0x8173910, _cmd=0x22f72) at /Users/MasonSilber/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/StuffNearMe/StuffNearMe/SavedAddressesViewController.m:40
3  0x0001c93f in -[SavedAddressesViewController initWithStyle:] (self=0x8173910, _cmd=0x6bfe690, style=UITableViewStylePlain) at /Users/MasonSilber/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/StuffNearMe/StuffNearMe/SavedAddressesViewController.m:28
4  0x0039e3b6 in -[UITableViewController init] ()
5  0x00016662 in -[StartPageViewController goToSavedAddresses:] (self=0x815fde0, _cmd=0x2222a, sender=0x852a100) at /Users/MasonSilber/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/StuffNearMe/StuffNearMe/StartPageViewController.m:409
6  0x0156e969 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
7  0x00176429 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
8  0x003ae993 in -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] ()
9  0x0156e969 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
10 0x00176429 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
11 0x001763be in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
12 0x0021d45f in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
13 0x0021d928 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
14 0x0021cbf3 in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
15 0x0019c7b4 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
16 0x0019c9dd in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
17 0x001820c0 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
18 0x0017590c in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
19 0x01d96876 in PurpleEventCallback ()
20 0x0153fff5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
21 0x014a4902 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
22 0x014a31ea in __CFRunLoopRun ()
23 0x014a2694 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
24 0x014a25ab in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
25 0x01d94fdf in GSEventRunModal ()
26 0x01d950a4 in GSEventRun ()
27 0x00173851 in UIApplicationMain ()
28 0x000023ca in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff5ec) at /Users/MasonSilber/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/StuffNearMe/StuffNearMe/main.m:16
```

I think it might have to do with managed object contexts (I don't quite understand them, or core data, yet), but I'm not sure. Any help is really really greatly appreciated, I am so lost trying to get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd help to know what the exception that's being thrown is. Let execution continue so you can see what's thrown.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't say. It's just a general SIGABRT with no message in the console.

Comment: Have you verified that `managedObjectContext` is live? Set`NSZombieEnabled` environment variable to `YES` as well.

Comment: I have NSZombieEnabled set already, no notifications have been thrown to the console by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the fetch request's managedObjectContext from `self.managedObjectContext` but you are executing the fetch request using the value return from each fetched results controller  managedObjectContext property.

That means you may have two or more different context involved or a nil value for one of the context. Since you get the exception from the NSEntityDescription call, the `self.managedObjectContext` is probably nil.

Unless you explicitly have two context for some reason, you should use only one reference to the context. In this case, you should always use `self.managedObjectContext` taking care that it is properly populated.

Comment: Thanks! Managed object contexts are still really confusing me, but now I think I'm on the right track. It's certainly not doing what I want it to do, but it's not crashing at that line, so thanks!

Comment: The context is what provides the "management" for "managed" objects. Just like with a human manager, its best to only have one so they don't interfere with one another. You usually don't have more than one context per thread/operation. If you have only one thread in an app, then you usually only have one context for the entire app.